# Preventing Maven Modules from being Deployed

Tags: maven

I followed [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/publish-your-artifacts-to-maven-central) to created a Maven build that can publish artifacts to Maven Central.

It works, and most of the tutorial is for authentication of some sort, so the only relevant part of it might just be:

```java
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now I wanted to only deploy two of the seven modules in total, so I added this to the parent POM:

```java
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And `<skip>false</skip>` to the two modules I actually want to deploy.

This doesn't work. All modules get deployed.

I checked the effective POM, and it clearly shows `skip=false` for the two modules I want to deploy and `skip=true` for the other five modules.

Since deploying to Maven Central isn't really a reversible process, I don't want to trial and error my way through this problem, hence the question: How do I prevent Maven modules from deploying to Maven Central?

Comment: First question: Why do you have 7 modules but only want to publish 2 of them? What purpose do the other modules have? Do you have a github repo?

Comment: @khmarbaise The other modules are for integration tests, release engineering, example code, documentation. They have code that runs against the rest of the project or automate some steps in the build process, so I believe they belong in the same reactor, still there is no real reason to ever deploy them. And there are some malicious people on SO, so I choose to not link to my GitHub account, but I'll gladly provide more details if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If you are deploying to Maven Central, it is the Nexus Staging Plugin that is doing the deployment instead of the Deploy plugin, so the configuration of the deploy plugin has no effect.  To make the Nexus deploy plugin skip, set `skipNexusStagingDeployMojo` in its configuration to `true`.

---

For a complete example, you can look at one of my projects I deployed to Maven Central with the same problem - I want to deploy everything except the integration test modules.

In the parent POM, the Nexus deploy plugin is defined like normal as described in the tutorial (https://bitbucket.org/prunge/shoelaces/src/2347535282c9f5bb58d33cca22d9dd65c9db2c2b/pom.xml#pom.xml-200):

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.8</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                    <autoReleaseAfterClose>false</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

and in the integration tests project (which itself has children that inherit this configuration) the staging plugin is skipped (https://bitbucket.org/prunge/shoelaces/src/2347535282c9f5bb58d33cca22d9dd65c9db2c2b/integration-tests/pom.xml#pom.xml-28):

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <skipNexusStagingDeployMojo>true</skipNexusStagingDeployMojo>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This results in everything by default being deployed to Central except the integration tests project and everything underneath that.

Comment: This setup prevents _all_ modules from being released for some reason. The only difference is I added `<autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>` but I don't see how that can lead to no releases at all. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: Pretty sure this worked for me.  Maybe it worked for me because of some nexus plugin shennigans (it replaces the deploy plugin in a non-standard way) and maybe the plugin configuration just clobbers what's already there regardless of project structure - which works for me because my integration tests always run last.  I haven't actually investigated/debugged, but if that is what's happening then maybe configuring `skipNexusStagingDeployMojo` to `true` or `false` explicitly for each subproject could work.

Comment: Explicitely defining it doesn't work either. Either all modules get deployed or none. =/